# Bootstrap / CSS - Fixing cross browser margin inconstencies for float-right image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to float right as far as possible an image that renders correctly in Chrome, but in FireFox it has incorrect margin top, it crosses the bottom divider.

```
Example in Chrome
+--------------+
|Category     X|
+--------------+

Example in FF (too much margin-top)
+--------------+
| Category     |
+------------X-+
```

How do I make the margins consistent between browsers when using float right on the image?

```
<li>
    <a>
              Category 2 (10%)
              <img class="pull-right" src="icon.svg">
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Can you give us a demo that illustrates the problem? These behave the same in firefox and chrome for me http://codepen.io/anon/pen/evaxKw here's a link on how to create a [mcve]

Comment: Looks more like that element has floated outside the container because of another issue. Put your code up in a pen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Application of the following rules in css solved the issue!

```
img{
      position: absolute;
      right: 0px;
      margin-top: 5px;  /* not mandatory but useful for vertical adjustment*/
}
```

Chrome and FF now behave identically!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried resetting margins and padding?

```
    <style> 
* {
margin:0;
padding:0 
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write different css for firefox only using

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    /* your css according to firefox */
}
```

And for internet Explorer

```
<!--[if IE]>
<style type='text/css'>
     /*your css according to IE */
<![endif]-->
```